# Using bind to utilize another Javascript class's method

Tags: javascript

I have an old-style class in Javascript that I want to utilize another old-style class's behavior without a full subclassing. Something like this:

```
function Foo(x) { 
  this.x = x;
}
Foo.prototype.add1 = function() {
  return this.x + 1
}
function Bar(n) {
  this.x = 2*n;
}
Bar.prototype.add1 = function() {
  // steal behavior from Foo.add1
  return Foo.prototype.add1.call(this);
}
```

This works fine in a browser console:

```
> b = new Bar(3)
Bar {x: 6}
> b.add1()
7
```

Is there a way to use `bind` instead? Something like

```
function Bar(n) {
  this.x = 2*n;
}
Bar.prototype.add1 = Foo.prototype.add1.bind(xyz);
```

except that there's no "this" object to use for `xyz` before the object actually exists.

The following code works, but seems wrong....

```
function Bar(n) {
  this.x = 2*n;
  this.add1 = Foo.prototype.add1.bind(this);
}
```

Is there a way to use `bind` in this way when setting up an old-style class's prototype?

Comment: why not `Bar.prototype.add1 = Foo.prototype.add1`

Comment: that will utilize `this` properly? (if so, could you respond as an answer?) somehow I never thought of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't need to use `bind`, just assign `Bar.prototype.add1 = Foo.prototype.add1`. `bind` method is useful for instances not for classes.